# Wizard with DialogFragments: Why two clicks on backbutton are required to pop Dialog from Backstack?

Tags: android, back-button, android-dialogfragment, back-stack

I want to schow a sequence of DialogFragments as a wizard.
I show the first with the following code:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = ConnectDialog.newInstance(Type.SELECT_EVENT);
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "connect");
```

To switch from the first to the second Dialog I use the following code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
DialogFragment newFragment = ConnectDialog.newInstance(Type.SELECT_ACTION);
transaction.remove(ConnectDialog.this);
transaction.add(newFragment, ConnectDialog.this.getTag());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

this code is called within an `OnClickListener` in `ConnectDialog` which is a subclass of `DialogFragment`.

When the second Dialog is shown one has to click twice the hardware back button to see the first dialog. I want,that the first dialog is shown again after only one back button click! How can I achieve that?

Comment: What happens if you remove the invocation of `add()` and replace the `commit()` with a single call to `show()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, I faced the same situation and I fixed that by replacing `dialog.dismiss()` to `fragmentManager.popBackStack();`